# Help Differential equations.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve $(x+2y^3)\frac{dy}{dx}=y$

The standard form is usually known as $\frac{dy}{dx}+Py=Q$. 
Can we use standard form as $\frac{dx}{dy}+Px=Q$ for this question and solve?
What is the answer?

Is this equation linear if we write it as $\frac{dx}{dy}+Px=Q$

Comment: Only linear differential equations have the form $dy/dx+Py=Q$. Your equation $(x+2y^3)dy/dx=y$ is non- linear.

Comment: it is linear when we write write it as dx/dy - x/y=2y^2??

Comment: No, since we have on the RHS $y^2$,

Comment: so this solution is wrong     https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dsDNnnNY-8U

Comment: how would u solve this then?

Comment: Are you sure the y^2 will cause problems cause i just saw someone say dy/dx=y^3/2x is in standard form.

Answer (score 1):

$$(x+2y^3)\frac{dy}{dx}=y $$
$$\frac{x}{y}+2y^2=\frac{dx}{dy} $$ $$\Rightarrow $$
$$ \frac{dx}{dy}-\frac{x}{y}=2y^2$$ Lagrange equation ;) and $$y=0 $$

Comment: The answer is $$ x=y^3+Cy $$ and $$ y=0$$